# vbscript unknown runtime error for excel

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error for "" at line 28 (If statement). I'm not sure what is the issue as I have defined everything correctly and make sure the paths are corrects. Can someone please help? I'm trying to grab corresponding group for each user from one sheet to another sheet. here is my code:

```
for each ColValue1 in objWorksheet1.Range("A1:A" & intlastrow1)
    introw1= introw1+1
    for each ColValue2 in objWorksheet2.Range("A1:A" & intLastRow2)
        introw2 = introw2+2
        if ColValue1 = ColValue2 then
            ...
```

Comment: What are ColValue1 and ColValue2 declared as? If you declared them as ranges, try if ColValue1.Value = ColValue2.Value then

Comment: VBScript or VBA? I assume it is VBA, VBS is something different. Also, what does the error say?

Comment: You can't compare objects, only properties of those objects. If those are ranges, try comparing their .Value or .Address properties, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The cells you are looping through should be declared as a range.  Then compare their values.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim ColValue1  As Range
Dim ColValue2  As Range

Set ColValue1 = ws.Range("A1")
Set ColValue2 = ws.Range("A2")

If ColValue1.Value = ColValue2.Value Then
    MsgBox "They are the same"
Else
    MsgBox "They are not the same"
End If
```